# Shiny observeEvent triggers on app launch

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have an app with `observeEvent`that triggers when the app starts, it doesn't wait for the button to be clicked. In this example it doesn't appear to have a difference but in my real app it causes the busyIndicator to show twice on the initial load.

```
name<-sample(c('a','b','c'),replace=T,5)
LAT<-runif(5,min=-26, max=-22)
LONG<-runif(5,min=-54, max=-48)
data<-data.frame(name,LAT,LONG)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput('muni',label='Select city',
              choices=c('Show all',sort(levels(data$name)),selected=NULL)),
  htmlOutput('box'),
  leafletOutput('map')
  ))

server <- function (input, output, session) {

data1<-reactive({
       if (input$muni!='Show all') {
           data<-data[which(data$name==input$muni),]
           }
       return(data)
})

output$box <- renderUI({

data<-data1()
num<-as.integer(nrow(data))

lapply(1:num, function(i) {
       bt <- paste0('go_btn',i)
       fluidRow(
                HTML(paste0('<div style="border: 1px solid #00000026; 
                border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;">
                <span style="font-size:14px font-weight:bold;">',
                data$name[i],' - areas: a1, a2, a3</span></br>',
                actionButton(bt,'See map',icon=icon('map-marker',lib='font-awesome')),
                HTML('</div></br>')
                )))
       })
    })

output$map<-renderLeaflet({

data<-data1()
rownames(data)<-seq(1:nrow(data))

leaflet(data) %>%
  addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>% 
  setView(-51.5,-24.8,zoom=7) %>% 
  addMarkers(lng=~data$LONG,lat=~data$LAT)

})

lapply(1:nrow(data), function(i) {
       observeEvent(input[[paste0('go_btn',i)]], {
                    data<-data1()
                    rownames(data)<-seq(1:nrow(data))

                    leafletProxy('map',data=data,session=session) %>%
                                 clearMarkers() %>%
                                 setView(data$LONG[i],data$LAT[i],zoom=15) %>%
                                 addMarkers(lng=data$LONG[i],lat=data$LAT[i])
        },ignoreInit = T)
     })
   }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Using `options(shiny.trace = TRUE)` I see that the process runs twice:
SEND {"busy":"busy"} SEND {"busy":"idle"}.
Can anyone tell me why my app is having this behavior?

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? The code has a couple issues that prevent it from running.

Comment: Sorry!! I deleted some variables from the dataframe and forgot not to declare them! Now I think it works...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run your example so I made my own:

```
library(shiny)

options(shiny.trace = TRUE)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  uiOutput("content")
))

server <- function (input, output, session) {
  output$content <- renderUI({
    actionButton("btn", "Button")
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    print("btn")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The console output for this is:

```
SEND {"config":{"workerId":"","sessionId":"1ceb44576d353c33bdc92e1eebba7ad0","user":null}}
RECV {"method":"init","data":{".clientdata_output_content_hidden":false,".clientdata_pixelratio":1,".clientdata_url_protocol":"http:",".clientdata_url_hostname":"127.0.0.1",".clientdata_url_port":"5326",".clientdata_url_pathname":"/",".clientdata_url_search":"",".clientdata_url_hash_initial":"",".clientdata_url_hash":"",".clientdata_singletons":"",".clientdata_allowDataUriScheme":true}}
SEND {"busy":"busy"}
SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"content","status":"recalculating"}}
SEND {"recalculating":{"name":"content","status":"recalculated"}}
SEND {"busy":"idle"}
SEND {"errors":[],"values":{"content":{"html":"<button id=\"btn\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default action-button\">Button<\/button>","deps":[]}},"inputMessages":[]}
RECV {"method":"update","data":{"btn:shiny.action":0}}
SEND {"busy":"busy"}
SEND {"busy":"idle"}
```

There are two "busy" messages. The first is from `observeEvent` executing its `eventExpr` (which is `NULL` at this time, so it doesn't execute `handlerExpr`). It always runs to check `eventExpr` even if `ignoreInit = TRUE`. The second busy comes from the initial rendering of dynamic UI.

Comment: So, is it impossible not to show the loading message twice because it is the normal behavior of shiny being busy, idle and then busy again? When I remove the observeEvent(input[[paste0('go_btn',i)]]) it doesn't appear to be busy twice.

Comment: You're right - one of those busy messages are from the observer and I revised my answer. There will always be a busy message from the observer checking if its event expression is truthy. But it doesn't necessarily mean the handler expression is run.